# How would I be able to make the width of the input be smaller to at the left?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
body {
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.cas {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #0C8346;
  background: #0C8346;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sad {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #D73909;
  background: #D73909;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.asd {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #D3D3D3;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p.sda {
  font-width: 700;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  >.col,
  >[class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

.sh {
  margin-left: -2px;
  width: 585px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-top: none;
}

.hs {
  margin-left: -17px;
  width: 587px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dasdasd.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6 cas">
          CONS
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 sad">
          PROS
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-6">
          <input type="input" name="as" class="asd hs">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <input type="input" name="as" class="asd sh">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/ulg/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'd like for the input under the cons to start where the cons starts, and to end where it ends now. Is this possible, or should I just make the pros and cons bigger? Or is there a better way to do it? Please help!! Also please go easy on me, I'm a beginner... Thank you so very much!!! Well that's all I want to ask, this is just filler...

Comment: `width: 585px;` <-- the culprit

Answer (score 0):

please add your styles

```css
        input, .title{
            width: 100%;
        }
        input{
            background: #D3D3D3;
        }
        .title--cons{
            background: #D73909;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .title--pros{
            background: #0C8346;
            color: #fff;
        }
        #pros-cons div[class^='col-']{
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dasdasd.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" id="pros-cons">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="title title--cons">
                CONS
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="title title--pros">
                PROS
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <input type="input" name="as" class="asd hs">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <input type="input" name="as" class="asd sh">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/ulg/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```